# Disable line color if met condition (pine script)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to disable line color if certain condition is met. But I'm having difficulty doing so.

Now the ploted line displayed as a connected line. But what I would like it to do is to display  as a disconnected the ploted line when `highPivot` is `na` or `sumCross_ph > 3`

Here is my code

```
ph = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
fix_ph  = fixnan(ph)[1]
Cross_ph = ta.crossover(close,fix_ph) or ta.crossunder(close,fix_ph) ? 1 : 0
var sumCross_ph = 0.0
sumCross_ph := ta.change(fix_ph) ? 0 : sumCross_ph + Cross_ph
highPivot = sumCross_ph >3 ? na : fix_ph

naColorHi = ta.change(highPivot) or na(highPivot)
plot(highPivot, color=naColorHi ? na : #FF0000,  linewidth=1, offset=-(rightBars+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply your color condition to the `series` argument of the `plot()` function.

Also, if you want to have disconnected line, you should change your plot's style to something like `plot.style_circles`.

```
plot(naColorHi ? highPivot : na, color=#FF0000, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, offset=-(rightBars+1))
```

Haven't tested it but should work.

Comment: @vitruvirus Thank you for you reply. I tried your code but it doesn't work. I want to plot value of `highPivot` and disable color if `highPivot` is changed or has `na` value (`naColorHi = ta.change(highPivot) or na(highPivot)`)